# pysvn getting previous version

Tags: python, python-2.7, pysvn

I am working on a script that searches the log for a particular string in log.message and populates all the the revisions having that particular string. But I would like to get the previous version to the one which has the first instance of the string. I am not able to come up with a way that would do this.

I currently have this:

I currently have this:

```
log_messages = client.log(work_path, limit=0)
usr_str = raw_input("Please enter the hook string:")

rev_list = []


tracking = True

for log in log_messages:

    if usr_str in log.message:

        timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(log.date))
        print '[%s]\t%s\t%s\n  %s\n' % (log.revision.number, timestamp,
                log.author, log.message)

        rev_num = log.revision.number
        revision =  client.export( work_path,
                                   dest_path+str(rev_num),
                                   recurse=False,
                                   revision=pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, rev_num))
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I currently have this

Answer (score 0):

There are two answer depending on what you will do with previous rev.

If you just want to do a diff then having figured out that the string is in rev N you can diff between N and N-1.

If you want to know the rev of the change before the file with the string you can call log() again providing the path the file, the start rev of N-1 and end rev of 0 with a limit of 1. The log returned will be the one you are after. Of course if the file was added in N then you do not need to look further.

Barry Scott author pysvn.